# Excel will not read date

Tags: excel, date, formulas

I've tried a million things to get Excel to read a date that is being pulled by this formula:

```
=(LEFT(VLOOKUP(C7,'Input Engagement Status'!C:M,9,FALSE),11))
```

I use `LEFT` because the cell I'm referencing is storing two dates simultaneously.  The output is "mmm dd yyyy".

I have tried text to columns, but the formula is being pulled apart rather than the date that it reads for.

I have tried custom formatting to create a new date format for "mmm dd yyyy". I have changed from general, to numbers, to text, and I am out of solutions at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample data that shows the two dates being stored in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

A way to illustrate the differences is with a date on the worksheet. Excel treats dates as 1 for every day past Dec 31, 1899. Today happens to be 42,192 (or 42192 as Excel sees it).

If you put `=TODAY()` in a cell (e.g. A1) and use `=RIGHT(A1, 2)`, the A1 cell probably shows 07/07/2015 but the underlying value is 42192 so the `RIGHT(A1, 2)` is going to return 92. Format the cell so it displays Tuesday, July 7, 2015 and `RIGHT(A1, 2)` is still going to return 92.

If you have two dates in the same cell separted by a space or other delimiter as a text string then you should be able to pull the first 11 characters from the string value and convert it back to a date with the [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-b5bd5892-0c18-4c78-be4a-d7b5b3525e23).

Using this data in a single cell (A1):

```
Jul 07 2015  Jul 15 2015
```

Use the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) to insert a comma so that DATEVALUE will resolve the date correctly.

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1, 11), " 20", ", 20"))
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1, 11), " 20", ", 20"))
```

Format the result as a date. The above will return 42,192 and 42,200 (the number of days since Dec 31, 1899). Format as a date to get something like 07/07/2015 and 07/15/2015.

You should be able to transcribe your [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) into that simple example.